# "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" when trying to get a user id

Tags: javascript, discord.js

during the development of my bot I encountered the following error:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

This is my code so far:

```
 const msg =  message.channel.send(gvg).then(async msg => {
  await msg.react(''); 
  await msg.react('');
  await msg.react('');
  await msg.react('⚙️');

  const filter = (reaction) =>  ['', '', '', '⚙️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
  
  const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter,{ time: 30000 }, {dispose : true });
  
  collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user ) => {
    const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '' ) { 
      member.roles.add('845380394513596446');
    } 

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
      member.roles.add('845380453597708299')
    }

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') { 
      member.roles.add('845380484964024330')
    }

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '⚙️') {
      member.roles.remove('845380484964024330')
      member.roles.remove('845380453597708299')
      member.roles.remove('845380394513596446')
    }
    
  });

  collector.dispose('remove', async (reaction, user,  ) => {
    const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '' ) { 
      member.roles.remove('845380394513596446');
    } 

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
      member.roles.remove('845380453597708299')
    }

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') { 
      member.roles.remove('845380484964024330')
    }

  });

})
```

I hereby try to achieve that when **retracting** a reaction, the `role` of the `user` is removed again.

Comment: Try logging `reaction` and `user` in your `'collect'` event

Comment: ReactionCollector#dispose expects the second parameter to be a User and not a function. Did you mean to do `collector.on('remove')`?

Comment: which line errors is

Comment: @HellCatVN the one below the collector.dispose

Comment: As first cmt try logging user in dispose method

Comment: @HellCatVN, i can't understand what you want to say